# : 1005 Can't create table `shop`.`role_user` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hey guys I tried too much stuff and read some blogs or discussion I didn't fix my problem I'm new in laravel this project. I got error when I want to create to database this error like

```
E:\xampp\htdocs\shop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:463
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `shop`.`role_user` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

  2   E:\xampp\htdocs\shop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:463
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

```
class CreateRoleAndPermissionTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('role_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('roles')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->primary(['role_id','user_id']);
        });

        Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();


            $table->foreign('role_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('roles')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->foreign('permission_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('permissions')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->primary(['permission_id','role_id']);
        });


    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('role_and_permission');
    }
```

Comment: Do you have table `users` somewhere defined?

Comment: Try to remove `->unsigned()` from all foreign keys. I guess `->increments()` creates a signed integer.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you, it is usually helpful to include what you have previously attempted, as well as as a detailed explanation of the issue you are attempting to solve. I would recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which offers several tips to this end.

As for right now, I think you should add more complete context of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change all instances of `integer` to `biginteger`, I am assuming you are using a current version of Laravel which changed the increment field to 'biginteger'. And `$table->increments('id');` to `$table->id();`